# Do Z-Transfer Functions have the Samle Step Response as S-Transfer Functions

Tags: z-transform

The Laplace transform of $e^{-at}$ is $G(s)=\frac{1}{s+a}$, and the Z-Transform of a discretely sampled version of the time domain function is $G(z)=\frac{z}{z-e^{-aT}}$.

When you multiple $G(s)$ by the laplace transform of a step input $1/s$ the result is $Y(s)=\frac{1}{s(s+a)}$, when $G(z)$ is multiplied by the z-domain step input $\frac{z}{z-1}$, the result is $\frac{z^2}{(z-1)(z-e^{-aT})}$.

This does not equal the Z transform that corresponds to the same time domain function as $Y(s)$, which is:

$$\frac{z(1-e^{-aT})}{a(z-1)(z-e^{-aT})}$$

Therefore, if you treat these transforms as transfer functions they have different step responses.  Why is that?

Comment: For understanding how the sampling operators acts on the signals in the Laplace/Fourier/Z domain, you have to use the Fourier transform of (tempered) distributions and  the [Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). Note also that in general the sampling operator doesn't commute with convolution by the step function.

Comment: And what the Shannon theorem says, is that If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-st} = F(s)$ then $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n) z^{-n}= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty F(\log z + 2i \pi k)$