# Converting from S-Domain Transfer Function to Z-Domain Transfer Function

Tags: laplace-transform, z-transform

I have the following transfer function in the S-Domain:

$$G(s)=\frac{a}{s+a}$$

I want to determine a transfer function in the Z-Domain that does a good job of modelling this system for a discrete time approximation.

Should I use the bilinear transformation:

$$s=\frac{2}{T}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}$$

$$G(z)=G(\frac{2}{T}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})$$

the impulse invariant transformation

$$G(z)=Z(L^{-1}(G(s))_{t=nT})$$

the step invariant transformation:

$$G(z)=(1-z^{-1})Z(L^{-1}(\frac{G(s)}{s})_{t=nT})$$

or something else?  (In the above, $Z$ is for Z-Transform and $L$ is for Laplace transform, I couldn't figure out how to do the fancy symbols)

What are the instances when I should use each type of transformation?

Comment: I answered in your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993568/do-z-transfer-functions-have-the-samle-step-response-as-s-transfer-functions) : see the [Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem) $\tilde{g}(n) = g(n/f_s ) \implies \tilde{G}(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty G(\log z + 2i \pi f_s k )$

Comment: And prior to sampling, we apply a low-pass filter (because of the Shannon theorem..)

Comment: Thank you for that reference.  The Shannon sampling theorem article you sent doesn't reference the step invariant z transformation.  What I don't understand is why the Z-Domain transfer function that results in the same impulse response as an S-Domain transfer function results in a different step response.

Comment: If I want the Z-Domain transfer function to work for an arbitrary input that is not a step or an impulse response, which transfer function should I use?